# ReactJs setState skips first letter

Tags: javascript, reactjs, setstate

Whenever i type something is search bar update the state, it skips the first letter. For example, if i write "asdf" it only shows "sdf".

I tried console.log before this line of code

`this.props.newQuery(this.state.newSearchQuery);`

and everything was working fine.

Please check the below code of App.js and SearchBar.js

Thanks

App.js

```
import React from 'react';

import SearchBar from './components/SearchBar';

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(){
    super();

    this.state = {
      searchQuery: '',
      fetchedData: []
    };
  }

  newQuery(query){
    this.setState({
      searchQuery: query
    });
  }

  onSearch(){
    const userInput = this.state.searchQuery;

    if(userInput !== '' && userInput !== ' '){
      const API_KEY = `https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/${userInput}`;

      fetch(API_KEY, {
        method: 'GET',
        headers: {
          Accept: 'application/json'
        }
      })
      .then(result => result.json())
      .then(data => this.setState({ fetchedData: data.results }));

      console.log('res', this.state.fetchedData);
    }
  }

  render(){
    return(
      <div className="App">
        <h2>Search Pokemos by Types</h2>
        <hr />
        <SearchBar onSearch={this.onSearch.bind(this)} newQuery={this.newQuery.bind(this)} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

SearchBar.js

```
import React from 'react';

class SearchBar extends React.Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            newSearchQuery: '' //this blank value get executed first when i console.log
        }
    }
    searchInput(event){
        this.setState({
            newSearchQuery: event.target.value
        });

        this.props.newQuery(this.state.newSearchQuery);

        console.log(this.state.newSearchQuery); // if i log "asdf", state on top "newSearchQuery" skips the first letter, a and shows "sdf" only.
    }

    render(){
        return(
            <div className="input-group">
                <input onChange={this.searchInput.bind(this)} className="form-control" placeholder="[eg. Ditto, Cheri, etc]" />

                <button onClick={this.props.onSearch} className="btn btn-success">Search</button>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default SearchBar;
```

Comment: Donot post images instead post the real code.

Comment: code added. thanks

Comment: You mean `console.log(this.state.newSearchQuery);` is logging wrong?

Comment: yes, it skips first letter of the string.
for example, when it should log "USA" it only logs "SA" by skipping "U".

Comment: I answer the question. This is problem is because **State Updates May Be Asynchronous**

Comment: Just to know, `setState` has a callback in 2nd argument which will occur after the state update. `setState({ name: "Michael" }, () => console.log(this.state));`

Answer (score 0):

The `console.log` doesnot log as expected because the `setState()` method is not always executed as its called. According to [Docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#state-updates-may-be-asynchronous)

> **State Updates May Be Asynchronous**:Because `this.props` and `this.state` may be updated asynchronously, you should not rely on their values for calculating the next state.

So when you are logging this `console.log(this.state.newSearchQuery);` after the `setState` the state is not actually changed so thats why it logs unexpected

Comment: But when i'm fetching the data, then first letter is also missing.
For example, if i search for "ditto" to fetch from pokeapi then it searchs for "ditt" instead of "ditto".

Comment: @Najam Khan use `console.log()` inside `.then` callback. If you could give me codepen so I would try to resolve the issue

Answer (score 0):

I'm a bit confused as to the redundant state between the two components.  What I think I would do (if I wasn't using something like mobx) is keep the state on the parent component and pass the `handleChange` and `handleSearch` functions to the `<Search />` component. It would look something like...

I threw together a codesandbox for you: https://codesandbox.io/s/n1ryz4rzwl

**APP Component**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import SearchBar from './components/SearchBar'

class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super()
    this.state = {
      searchQuery: '',
      fetchedData: []
    }
  }

  handleChangeQuery = event => this.setState({searchQuery: event.target.value})

  handleSearch = () => {
    const {searchQuery} = this.state,
      API_KEY = `https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/${searchQuery}`;

    fetch(API_KEY, {
      method: 'GET',
      headers: {
        Accept: 'application/json'
      }
    })
    .then(result => result.json())
    .then(data => this.setState({ fetchedData: data.results }));
  }

  render() {
    const {searchQuery} = this.state
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <h2>Search Pokemos by Types</h2>
        <hr />
        <SearchBar
          value={searchQuery} 
          handleChangeQuery={this.handleChangeQuery} 
          handleSearch={this.handleSearch}  
        />

        // Show fetchedData results here

      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default App
```

**SearchBar Component** - *This COULD be a stateless functional component*

```
import React from 'react'

const SearchBar = ({value, handleChangeQuery, handleSearch}) => {
  return (
    <div className="input-group">
      <input 
        onChange={handleChangeQuery} 
        value={value}
        className="form-control" 
        placeholder="[eg. Ditto, Cheri, etc]" 
      />
      <button onClick={handleSearch} className="btn btn-success">Search</button>
    </div>
  )
}

export default SearchBar
```

The reasoning behind the strange missing character has been described by the other comments - as the `this.setState()` may be async.  However, `this.setState()` does have a callback function that can be used to confirm the change if you want to test with that.  It looks something like:

```
this.setState({key: value}, () => {
  // State has been set
  console.log(this.state.key)
})
```